# Is it possible to supply template parameters when calling operator()?

Tags: c++, templates, operator-overloading

I'd like to use a template `operator()` but am not sure if it's possible. Here is a simple test case that won't compile. Is there something wrong with my syntax, or is this simply not possible?

```
struct A {
  template<typename T> void f() { }
  template<typename T> void operator()() { }
};

int main() {
  A a;
  a.f<int>();           // This compiles.
  a.operator()<int>();  // This compiles.
  a<int>();             // This won't compile.
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Not with shorthand syntax, no.

Comment: [edited] Can you show us how the operator uses `T`?

Comment: @MarkB Just one example: `throw T` or `return T` (which is not the case here but would also be not deduced).

Comment: @MarkB The function does depend on `T`, but I was trying to provide a minimal example here.

Comment: What are you trying to do? It seems you're *trying* to use the **wrong** tool.

Comment: @Paul You mean the function *implementation* depends on `T` or the signature depends? If the signature depends, template type deduction might be possible (but there are cases where it is not). One trick (not always possible) is to *add a dummy parameter just for type deduction*, like `operator()(T dummy)`, then call it with `a(int())`. It will be optimized away so there is no runtime overhead cost involved, but it requires `T` to have a default constructor without side effects. But I'm not sure if this is really more readable than `a.operator()<int>()`.

Comment: @leemes The function implementation depends on `T`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Like chris mentioned in the comments, no, not with the shorthand syntax. You must use the full `.operator()<T>()` syntax;

Comment: I dub it the `T`-_fighter invocation_.

Comment: @Xeo Best answer yet :-)

Answer (score 4):

If you *really* want to use templated `operator()` and want to avoid writing constructions like `a.operator()<int>();` you can add an auxiliary parameter to it:

```
template <typename T>
struct type{};

struct A
{
    template<typename T>
    void operator()(type<T>) { }
};

int main()
{
    A a;

    a(type<int>());
}
```

[**Live demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/33e76064b260889f).

---

In C++14 you can even omit empty brackets in `a(type<int>());` via a variable template:

```
template <typename T>
struct type_{};

template <typename T>
constexpr type_<T> type{};

struct A
{
    template<typename T>
    void operator()(type_<T>) { }
};

int main()
{
    A a;

    a(type<int>);
}
```

[**Live demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fde6140680fef1e8).

Answer (score 2):

The exact syntax you want to use is not possible in the C++ language.

Depending on the *real* problem you're trying to solve (which isn't in the question), I can think of at least three options:

- Use a named function instead of the operator.
- Template `A` instead of the operator itself.
- Use the verbose spelling to call the `operator()` (I'm not a big fan of this option).